# MySQL insert not working on new table

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I am doing an insert on the MySQL table "analytics" with the fields "a_id" (PRIMARY and UNIQUE), "a_query" and "a_date".

My code:

```
function queryanalytics($clsendquery) {
     $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     $connection = connectsql();
     $sql = "INSERT INTO analytics (a_query,a_date) VALUES (?,?)";
     $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bind_param('ss',$clsendquery,$datetime);
     $stmt->execute;
     $stmt->close();
 }
```

Nothing updates in the database and $stmt->affected_rows returns 0.
There are no errors in $stmt->error or $connection->error.
When I run the insert in phpMyAdmin it works fine.

I have other selects and inserts that work fine with the same connection, why does this one not?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stmt->execute;` should be `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: Welp, I sat at this for 2 days. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rohr Accept the answer so this question be marked as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Just need to wait 9 minutes it seems.